# Text replace literally *all* instances of a string through stdin, stdout

Tags: stdout, stdin

Linux, or specifically Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server if necessary (and CENTOS 6.5/7 minimal would be nice).

If I enter "FOO" at the command line, (regardless of whether as a word or as a substring), I'd like for the shell (I use BASH, but I'm willing to switch if needed) to replace it with "BAR", *before* executing it, or submitting the string (keyword, param., whatever) to an application.

If STDOUT is about to output "BAR", I would like it to instead display "FOO", regardless of whether "BAR" is a separate string or a substring.

An ideal solution would be compatible with GNU Screen, and be case-insensitive.
Any solution *must* work over SSH.

Mappings should be quick and fairly simple to create (e.g.: STDIN:"FOO"->"BAR"; STDOUT:"BAR"->"FOO").
The only exception to the text translation/conversion would perhaps have to be when modifying the mappings file. (I use FOO and BAR, but in practice my (sub)strings will be almost certainly unique, such that undesired translations would never occur.)

How can I make this happen ?

Has anyone done this before ?

UPDATE : For my use, string replacement only needs to take place when the Enter key is hit. 
For example, if typing f,o,o in Vim, where each character is printed immediately, no replacement would be done (how could it ?), so I'd see just "foo". 
Hopefully that makes things easier.

Comment: The first part can be done with an `alias`. Not sure on the second.

Comment: You realise that it would need to delay the output. If something outputs BA and pauses, you'd need to wait for the next char to see if it's R or not.

Comment: Also, on input, what if the user enters `FOR\bO`. How could your wrapper handle that?

Comment: This could be done by modifying the `script` command to monitor the input and output, looking for the strings and replacing them. I don't think there's any standard mechanism to do this.

Comment: Most Unix shells use the `readline` library to handle their command-line input.  You could probably do some fancy things with an `.inputrc` file to modify these lines however you want prior to sending them to the shell.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html

Comment: @NealFultz: The question says, "replace literally *all* instances of a string ..." and "regardless of whether as a word or as a substring". Absent clarification, I would guess that the OP wants to be able to type `cat food` and have it translated to `cat bard`. That's way more than can be done with an alias.

Comment: G-Man : Yes, alias isn't sufficient.   

@StéphaneChazelas : I suppose the output might need to be delayed, say stored temporarily (albeit very briefly) in a buffer for parsing before being output, but that's acceptable. On a half-decent machine I wouldn't expect a delay of more than 1 second, and that's acceptable. 
"...on input, what if the user enters FOR\bO" - I'm not sure what the "R\b" means, but I get the gist of what you're saying. Fortunately I will be "the user" so I can simply avoid doing that. ;-)   

Barmar, dg99 : Thank you for the leads, I'll look into script and readline.

Comment: Do you want that only if you type in the shell, or if you type in any application running in the terminal? By `\b`, Stéphane means backspace: if you type `F`, `O`, `R`, backspace, `O`, then should this insert `FOO` or `BAR`?

Comment: @Gilles: Ah, I see what you mean. Good question. I want to see F,O,R,[backspace],O as I type it, but as soon as I hit enter, I want FOO changed to BAR (after my having corrected the typo) for whatever application is running that receives the text/command.
Is that clarification inconsistent with my question as originally asked ? I'm not familiar with the terminology. 

Using G-Man's example, if I'm at the prompt and I enter "cat food", "cat bard" will be executed. 

Actually, thinking about it more now, I can see issues with typing in, say, Vim, where characters are printed immediately. Hm...

Comment: @user2304437 The wanted behaviour seems to be difficult to achieve. Maybe it is a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there is another way to solve your (real) issue. `zsh` has for example different ways to do text replacement, see e.g. [here](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/zleiab) or [the global alias feature](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/aliasglobal).